# Incrementing a column value in HBase that is versioned

Tags: hbase

I have a HBase table "t" with column family "f" with versions as 2

```
create 't', {NAME => 'f', VERSIONS => 2}
```

I have one row in this table with key say 'r1' and I have a column 'c1' with 2 version timestamped with values as follows

```
put 't','r1','f:c1', 1, 12345678
put 't','r1','f:c1', 2, 12345679
```

Now I want to increase f.c1 with version timestamp "12345678" by 10. Is this a possible operation in HBase. I checked the docs, but didn't find any.

Any suggestions? I don't want to read first and then write back coz there could be more than one thread updating this column and there is huge amount of data, so 2 operations(get and then put) is not a feasible option.

Comment: there is a solution to increase f.c1 with version timestamp "12345678" by 10, but it's also get and put on server side, so you will get the result '11' from a cell with another timestamp...it that you want or you just want to change the cell with  timestamp "12345678" to be '11' ?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comment, you can managed to increase `f.c1` with timestamp `12345678` by `10`, which means that after you invoke incr, the latest value of the column in that row will be `11`. The related java code is :

```
        incr.setTimeRange(12345678L, 12345679L);
```

But there is no api to set the timestamp of that cell when invoke incr, I think you can achieve that by implementing a coprocessor yourself.